# Insert value into String after the last slash

Tags: c#, regex

I need to insert some string value after the last slash. I have such string value:

```
string url = "http://blog.loc/blog/news/sport/slug1_slug2_slug3-slug";
```

I need to get this value:

```
"http://blog.loc/blog/news/sport/hot_slug1_slug2_slug3-slug"
```

So, I need to insert `hot_` (for example), after the last slash. Could anyone help me?

Comment: You have tagged this regex, do you want the answer to be regex too (as that's not necessarily needed)?

Comment: I just need any good solution for this)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know you asked for regex, but it's not really necessary in my opinion.

You can just use [string.Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string url = "http://blog.loc/blog/news/sport/slug1_slug2_slug3-slug";

url = url.Insert(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, "hot_");
```

url now holds the value: `http://blog.loc/blog/news/sport/hot_slug1_slug2_slug3-slug`

Comment: Beat me by seconds ... .:)

Comment: While correct I don't like the assumption that LastIndexOf returns a correct position in the test string

Comment: LastIndexOf is there as an easy example of getting the correct index. I'm sure OP can work out his own way if he finds it unreliable.

Comment: Some servers interpret urls ending with a `/` the same way as urls without the `/`.  For this reason, this answer isn't as robust as it could be imo

Answer (score 2):

Regex Method :

```
string url = "http://blog.loc/blog/news/sport/slug1_slug2_slug3-slug";
var matches = Regex.Matches(url, "/");
var match = matches[matches.Count - 1];
string result = url.Insert(match.Index + 1, "hot_")
```